# Informal way to say "contrary to popular belief"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Example:

> Contrary to popular belief, depression is more about 'hows' than
>   'whys'. And sometimes we even use logic to try to justify it.

I think *contrary to popular belief* is too formal. Is another way of saying it? (I thought about phrases with *unlike*, but I think that word is kind of formal, too).

Comment: ***Forget what you think you know***, I don’t think it’s too formal.  It’s said in casual conversation all the time.  So is ***Despite what you may have heard***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something along the lines of

> Despite what (many) people (often) think/assume/believe

e.g.

> **Despite what people think**, depression is more about 'hows' than 'whys'. And sometimes we even use logic to try to justify it.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

*Most people don't know this, but* depression is more about 'hows' than 'whys'. And sometimes we even use logic to try to justify it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *it's nothing but an **[urban legend](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/urban-legend)*** (also *urban myth*)

> A humorous or horrific story or piece of information circulated as though true, especially one purporting to involve someone vaguely related or known to the teller.

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Comment: This seems to capture the opposite of the desired expression... OP wants something like "*despite* the urban legend..."

Comment: @CalebBernard Exactly! I am suggesting that *urban legend* is parallel to *popular belief*, not the whole phrase ***contrary** to popular belief*

Answer (score 0):

You might say, "it might surprise you that" or "I was shocked to find out that." If you want to be especially informal, you could use "go figure."

Answer (score 0):

[*"It's a little-known fact..."*](http://welton1.tripod.com/Clavin_Quotes.html)

[-Cliff Clavin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliff_Clavin)

(Do not actually use.  Admirably succinct, though.)